# Capturing network traffic while debugging a web service

Tags: windows-10, soapui, fiddler, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 to run a web service and using SoapUI to call that service.  I've been able to update the proxy in SoapUI to use 127.0.0.1:8888 to see the requests from SoapUI hit my web service.  I'm using Fiddler to capture those requests

The web service then makes a couple of database calls, a REST service call, and a socket connection.  I've tried updating the machine.config and the Web.config with the following:

```
  <!-- The following section is to force use of Fiddler for all applications, including those running in service accounts -->
<system.net>
<defaultProxy
                enabled = "true"
                useDefaultCredentials = "true">
  <proxy autoDetect="False" bypassonlocal="False" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" usesystemdefault="False" />
</defaultProxy>
```

But I never see any request in Fiddler.  I'm also using Windows 10.  I've seen reference to having to change the userID of the IIS application server, but haven't found a reference on how to change the user when launching an IIS Express via Visual Studio.  Also my understanding is the Web.Config changes is all that I need to do, but would like some confirmation because it is not working.  I've also rebooted everything and still capture nothing while debugging the service.

Should I be able to see this traffic (SQL, REST calls, socket connections) and if so what am I doing wrong?